# Request permission dialog blackout the activity and pressing any key is closing the activity

Tags: android, permissions, runtime, android-6.0-marshmallow

I dont know why this happening just for one app because i tried it on other apps it works fine. But only this app whenever i request a permission the activity blacks out and only the permission dialog appears then pressing "Allow" or "Deny" will close the activity and i need to reopen it. 
I am suspecting that this behavior is happening upon some varieties upon themes or extending types of the Activity like "AppCompactActivity" or "ActionBarActivity".

This is my code

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&& ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Log.e("Permission","Granted");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("Permission","Not Granted");
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

and this is the themes but its only a suspect that the theme is the reason

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primary_orange_lighter</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Splash_Activity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_orange_lighter</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Login_Activity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_orange_lighter</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Main_Activity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_orange_lighter</item>
</style>


<style name="StarRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
</style>

<style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:color">#FFFFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/trans_white</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>

</style>

<style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="AppTheme.Main_Activity">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_orange_lighter</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary_orange_lighter</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">false</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomLoadingDialog" parent="SpotsDialogDefault">
    <item name="DialogTitleAppearance">@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium</item>
    <item name="DialogTitleText">Loading</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="DialogSpotCount">5</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="SwitchButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4dp</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

and this is the class where the request is occurring

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import syncworx.com.kunhadi_driver.R;
import syncworx.com.kunhadi_driver.classes.Constants;

public class Test_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED&& ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Log.e("Permission","Granted");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e("Permission","Not Granted");
            }

            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what we do with code and themes files? please add them

Comment: @SohailZahid i added them

Comment: OnPause or onstop methods have overide them

Comment: have you use on Pause methods or OnStop methodd in your activity.

Comment: Nope only onCreate

Comment: add your full class

Comment: @SohailZahid Done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121707/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-haidar).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally after two days struggling with this issue i found out what is the problem
Well let me post first the problem origin

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Splash_Activity.this, Test_Activity.class);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intent .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

As you see here when i am starting the Test_Activity which is the Activity i am requesting permission in it, i am adding some flags to the intent that is starting it so that when this activity is no longer visible it will be destroyed automatically, and it seems that requesting a permission does blocks the activity as if it is no longer visible so it is getting destroyed and then there is blackout behind the permission dialog because there is no activity alive anymore and then pressing deny or allow will simply dismiss the dialog and send a callback to the onRequestPermissionsResult method but the activity is not alive to receive the callback

Comment: I know this is an old question but how did you resolve the issue? I'm facing the exact same behavior.

Comment: You have explained what happened, not the solution. And point out where the problem begins. Additionally you said the activity is not alive.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is with the flags I added initially to the intent. If you have these flags added to the intent that is starting the activity where you are requesting the permission, then remove them.

Comment: So, where did you put on the flags? It seems you wanted no history and clear top

Comment: I removed the flags and handled these actions in different ways

Comment: Can you explain how did you do that?

Comment: sorry, i don't have access anymore to the project. I stopped working for the company who owned the project I was working on when I had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Intro activity had this flag:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:noHistory="true"
     />
```

to solve the issue get rid of it:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    />
```

The no history flag works without issues for all tested SDK, except 23!
A very hard to debug issue. I blamed  the library I was using https://github.com/AppIntro/AppIntro. Spend a full work day writing my own Intro, just to realize, asking for permission in the intro, with this flag in SDK 23 will "pause" your App and bring the phone home screen back to focus. Or in other words the permission dialog "stops" the app/intro.

Before Android 6, SDK 23, there are no permission requests. With Android 7, SDK 24, this issue doesn't exist. It might be a bug in ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(). Clearly the behaviour is NOT SDK independent.
Adding this answer to help Google searches with these keywords.